# Formatting XML with tabulation and removing element ending space?

Tags: c#, xml, formatting

I am trying to do 2 things:

1. Get the output XML formated with
   TABULATION instead of spaces.
2. Remove the ending space it generates
   for video element.

   ```
   " />
   ```

   to

   ```
   "/>
   ```

I have tried to use

```
xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

as well as

```
IndentChar
```

but they did not worked for me dont know why.

This is the code I have currently, I would also like to hear advices and suggestion to improve it:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'");
xmlWriter.WriteComment(@" This file was made by @author");
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("videos");
xmlWriter.Close();

xmlDoc.Load(filename);
XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
foreach (int myID in ExportListIDs)
{
    XmlElement video = xmlDoc.CreateElement("video");
    root.AppendChild(video);
    video.SetAttribute("videoID", myID.ToString());
}

xmlDoc.Save(filename);
```

Comment: `XmlWriter` has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlWriter.Create` instead. Why do you care about "formatting" anyway?

Comment: it does not work with XmlWriter.Create either

Comment: Why on earth do you care about that trailing space?  What non-conformant XML processor are you feeding this output to?

Comment: feeding to another program that i have no control over and it breaks if there is a space there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve question 1 with the below code but I still don't know if it is possible to remove the space between `"` and `/>` at the end of an element vide question 2.

```
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = "\t";

        XmlWriter writeXML = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml", settings);
        writeXML.WriteStartDocument();
        writeXML.WriteComment(@" This file was made by @author");

        writeXML.WriteStartElement("videos");

        foreach (var item in myList)
        {
            writeXML.WriteStartElement("video");
            writeXML.WriteAttributeString("ID", item.Key.ToString());
            writeXML.WriteAttributeString("Name", item.Value);
                writeXML.WriteStartElement("object");
                writeXML.WriteAttributeString("A", item.Key.ToString());
                writeXML.WriteAttributeString("B", item.Value);
                writeXML.WriteEndElement();
            writeXML.WriteEndElement();
        }

        writeXML.WriteEndElement();
        writeXML.WriteEndDocument();
        writeXML.Close();
```